# Why does unobtrusive validation not recognize culture correctly?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an MVC webapp which uses JQuery's unobtrusive validation for editing.  When the user picks their language (in their preferences), I have it changing:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = {selected culture};
```

This changes the entire site over to the new culture, including all resx references, presentation of dates (using . instead of /) and numbers (using , instead of . for the decimal point).

The only part of the app which does not automatically respond to this change is the unobtrusive validation.  The text fields display dates and numbers in the correct culture, but the validation ignores the selected culture, and does not validate dates and numbers as expected.

What needs to be changed to tell jquery to use a different culture?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Though it's now quite old, this [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) by Scott Hanselman helped me globalize jQuery validation. Also, check out the GitHub repo for [jQuery Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize).

Comment: Thank you - I don't think I had seen this one.  This looks very comprehensive.